# c3.js - Tooltips on xgrid lines

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, c3.js

is it possible to have tooltips when hovering over xgrid lines when using c3.js?

```
var chart1 = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart1',
    padding: {
      right:30
    },
    data: {
          x: 'x',
          xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
          columns:
          [
              ['x', '2013-01-01 00:00', '2013-01-01 01:00','2013-01-01 03:00','2013-01-01 04:00', '2013-01-01 05:00', '2013-01-01 06:00', '2013-01-01 07:00', '2013-01-01 08:00', '2013-01-01 09:00', '2013-01-01 10:00', '2013-01-01 11:00','2013-01-01 12:00','2013-01-01 13:00', '2013-01-01 14:00', '2013-01-01 15:00', '2013-01-01 16:00', '2013-01-01 17:00', '2013-01-01 18:00', '2013-01-01 19:00', '2013-01-01 20:00', '2013-01-01 21:00', '2013-01-01 22:00', '2013-01-01 23:00'],
              ['RX', 20, 10, 9, 20, 30, 20, 20, 20, 32, 20, 10, 9, 20, 30, 20, 20, 20, 32, 23, 12, 5, 14, 15],
          ],
          type: 'spline',
          colors: {
            RX:'#2d74d0',
          },
        },
        tooltip: {
          order: null,
        },
        point: {
          show: false
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'timeseries',
                tick: {
                  multiline: false
                }
            },
            y: {
              tick: {
                format: function (y) { return y + 'GB'}
              }
            }
        }
    }
).xgrids.add([
  {value: '2013-01-01 01:00', text: '01:00, Network 1'},
  {value: '2013-01-01 02:28', text: '02:28, Network 2'}
]);
```

I posted an example on jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/tekp7vvc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can poke it into using a basic 'title' based tooltip with the following addition to your c3 setup:

```
onrendered: function () {
  var xg = d3.selectAll(".c3-xgrid-lines text");
  xg.each (function (d,i) {
        var title = d3.select(this).select("title");
      if (title.empty()) {
        title = xg.append("title");
      }
      title.text (function (d) {
        return "Gridline: "+d.value+", "+d.text;
      })
  })
},
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tekp7vvc/1/

It's set to work when hovering over the gridline text as otherwise it would be competing with the functionality for showing the data in a tooltip if a gridline was at the same position as a datapoint (which the 1.00am datapoint is)

It's also set up to run in onrendered rather than oninit, because at the time oninit is called your gridlines haven't been added yet.

Comment: Although I see your code in the fiddle, I don't see any differences..?

Comment: Hover over the text on the gridlines

Comment: ..hmm. I see what you did there - but I had something different in mind. Despite the values I used in the sample, it is highly unlikely that a xgrid line would be exactly on top of a usual grid line. Now that I thought about it a bit better, would it be possible, to add these as additional tickValues so that the normal tooltip appears?

Comment: I'll give it to you as correct, although it wasn't exactly what I was looking for

Comment: You can't add them as tick values, as they wouldn't trigger tooltips unless that had corresponding data values to go with them (i tried make the data 'nulls' and doing the 'connectNull:true' thing, but the tooltips weren't appearing)